# Renewing the \thelstlisting command when hyperref is on

Tags: formatting, hyperref, cross-referencing, listings, microtype

I'm trying to change the appearance of the cross-ref to a listing in the appendix, so that it prints as `\textsc{a}.1`, not just `A.1`. The redefinition  `\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\MakeLowercase{\thechapter}.\arabic{lstlisting}}` works well when hyperref is off. Similar redefinitions for `\thefigure` and `\thetable` work with hyperref, but not this one for `\thelstlisting`. 
I can make it work by using `\lowercase`, but I still need `\textsc` then for the full redefinition,`\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\textsc{\lowercase{\thechapter}}.\arabic{lstlisting}}`, and that again doesn't work.

Check it yourself:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}

% once you make everything work, try with
% \usepackage{microtype}


\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single}


\begin{document}
% \MakeLowercase does not work here
% \lowercase does
\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\MakeLowercase{\thechapter}.\arabic{lstlisting}}
%  but what I really want is
% \renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\thechapter}}.\arabic{lstlisting}}
%and that does not work again

% always OK
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\textsc{\lowercase{\thechapter}}.\arabic{table}}

\chapter{Title}

Some text with a cross-ref to two listings \ref{chapter_listing}
\ref{appendix_listing} and a table \ref{appendix_table} at the end.

Expected: 1.1 and \textsc{a}.1 (not \textsc{A}.1)

\vspace{6cm}


\begin{lstlisting}[caption={first caption},label={chapter_listing}]
a few lines
of
pseudocode will hopefully do
\end{lstlisting}


\appendix

\chapter{Appendix test}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={second caption},label={appendix_listing}]
a few lines
of
pseudocode will hopefully do
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{table}
\caption{\label{appendix_table}table caption}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
first & second\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Where's the catch?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one option: A redefinition of `\thelstlisting` and `\thetable` (and others...) to `{\scshape\alph{chapter}}.\arabic{<cntr>}` when you reach `\appendix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{{\scshape\thechapter}.\arabic{table}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{{\scshape\thechapter}.\arabic{lstlisting}}%
}
\let\oldappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \oldappendix
  \renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{{\scshape\alph{chapter}}.\arabic{lstlisting}}
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{{\scshape\alph{chapter}}.\arabic{table}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

Some text with a cross-ref to two Listings~\ref{chapter_listing}
and~\ref{appendix_listing} and a Table~\ref{appendix_table} at the end.

Expected: 1.1 and \textsc{a}.1 (not \textsc{A}.1)

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={first caption},label={chapter_listing}]
a few lines
of
pseudocode will hopefully do
\end{lstlisting}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix test}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={second caption},label={appendix_listing}]
a few lines
of
pseudocode will hopefully do
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{table}
  \caption{\label{appendix_table}table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've used `{\scshape ...}` instead of `\textsc`.

Comment: Thanks @Werner.  I'm still wondering what caused the problem, or - what's the best way of discovering what's causing it in such cases. When one looks at the original definitions of all these macros it's like a vicious circle. What I've noticed is that `\meaning` on `\thechapter` before and after the beginning of the appendix shows they already have `\@arabic` or `\@Alph` plus `\c@chapter` in. And I made things work by `\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{{\scshape\lowercase{\thechapter}}.\arabic{lstlisting}}`. Do I know why this worked and `\MakeLowercase` hasn't? No!

Comment: My happiness didn't last long. This all is to be used with a package that calls microtype.sty. Then again nothing works if hyperref is on. Why?!

Answer (score 4):

The unexpandable stuff (`\lowercase`, `\textsc`, `\MakeLowercase`) must not appear in any counter value, which is used in anchor names. Package `hyperref` already uses `\theH<counter>` instead of `\the<counter>`. But it fails for `\theHstnumber`, because it uses `\thelstlisting` instead of `\theHlstlisting`.

Fix:

```
\documentclass[english]{report}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{%
  \textsc{\MakeLowercase{\thechapter}}.\arabic{lstlisting}%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\theHlstnumber}{%
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty
    \lst@neglisting
  \else
    \theHlstlisting % fixed: \theHlstlisting instead of \thelstlisting
  \fi
  .\thelstnumber
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thetable}{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\thechapter}}.\arabic{table}}

\chapter{Title}

Some text with a cross-ref to two listings \ref{chapter_listing}
\ref{appendix_listing} and a table \ref{appendix_table} at the end.

Expected: 1.1 and \textsc{a}.1 (not \textsc{A}.1)

\vspace{6cm}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={first caption},label={chapter_listing}]
a few lines
of
pseudocode will hopefully do
\end{lstlisting}


\appendix

\chapter{Appendix test}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={second caption},label={appendix_listing}]
a few lines
of
pseudocode will hopefully do
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{table}
\caption{\label{appendix_table}table caption}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
first & second\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(Images omitted, because the small caps lower chapter letters in references are dead ugly IMHO).

Comment: Thanks @Heiko. Hope this will be fixed in hyperref soon. (I agree, lower small caps look ugly... with this general /lack of/ style. Things reverse with old style figures and such stuff)

Comment: @PhilipPirrip The macro `\theHlstnumber` is defined in `lstmisc.sty`. Therefore it needs to be fixed in package `listings`.